# How can I reverse a name in PHP?

Tags: php

How can I reverse a name in PHP?

I have created a form in html and am trying to reverse code in PHP.

Like UserName || Age and save it in the database.

```
$username =  $_POST['uname'];
$age      =  $_POST['age'];
$query    =  "INSERT INTO user_info(user_name,user_age) VALUES ('$user','$userage')";
$res      =  mysql_query($query);
```

But when I save it in the database it is saved in the reverse order: `umer` instead of `remu`.

The reverse name `remu` is saved in the database. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: From where you have posted..??through ajax..??

Comment: How is it getting reversed in the first place?  Probably better to find and fix that than to reverse it again.

Comment: *Obligatory:* The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 5):

Use [`strrev()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php):

```
echo strrev($_POST['uname']);
```

**Note:** PHP has over a hundred [string functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php). Learning them will make you a [better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: @Gautam3164, only by one second this time :)

Comment: I'll give you one for balance :)

Comment: @Dave iam just joking yaar..if my ans is correct I will also get right..??

Comment: @Dave, the same *note* applied. Far too many PHP devs aren't aware of the native functions at their disposal.

Comment: Really thns Jason

But if I Use MVC thn what is the Code..

Here it is my code
class Model
{
 public function savedata($student)
 {  
  $user   = $student->getName();
  $userage = $student->getAge();
  $rev = strrev($userage);
//database query 
  $query  = "INSERT INTO user_info(user_name,user_age) VALUES ('$user','$rev')";
  $res  = mysql_query($query);
  return $res;
 } 
}

Comment: @JasonMcCreary yes there are an awful lot who don't know any of the native functions (or they lack the ability to use php.net docs and google!) but to be more fair there are several thousand of them its hard to remember them all.  Having said that even if you don't know what you want it rarely takes less than 20 seconds on google to find it

Answer (score 2):

Try like

```
$username =  strrev($_POST['uname']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

`$query    =  "INSERT INTO user_info(user_name,user_age) VALUES ('$user','".strrev($userage)."')";`